# div won't center with normalize.css

Tags: css, centering, normalize

For some reason when I add normalize.css to my code my div won't center within it's container.

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="myDiv">
    </div>
</div>
```

and

```
#wrap {
height:100%;
width:100%;
text-align:center;
}

#myDiv {
height:30%;
width:60%;
background:#999999;
}
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/msteeledunn/3xw1t6yo/

Comment: @CatalinLungu That fixed it. thanks for the help. If you make your comment an answer I'll choose it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Add `margin: 0 auto;` to myDiv CSS

Answer (score 0):

To center horizontally you just need to add an automatic left and right margin to the `div` you want to position in the center. (This works for all elements with `display:block`, which is the default display attribute for div elements)

```
#myDiv {
  height:30%;
  width:60%;
  background:#999999;
  margin: 0 auto; /*Center horizontally*/
}
```

Keep in mind that you need to set a width for this to work. either in percentages or pixels.

http://jsfiddle.net/3xw1t6yo/2/

Answer (score -1):

Your`text-align: center` is just going to center the text inside the div. You need to center the div with the following

```
#myDiv {
   height:30%;
   width:60%;
   background:#999999;
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```